# Probability: Number of guesses to get the "correct" item from a set, after repetitions

Tags: probability

Suppose a friend has N overturned cups on the table, one of which (chosen by the friend at random) has a ball underneath, and you have to keep guessing until you get it right; whenever you guess the wrong cup, that cup is removed, so you have a smaller set to choose from (but the ball is always under the same cup).

At the start, how many guesses should I suspect I'll have to make before I pick the right one, on average?

Comment: Are you asking at which guess your probability of picking right is now 50%? Or are you asking this: at the start, how many guesses should I take to have a 50% chance of one of those guesses being correct?

Comment: At the start, how many guesses will I likely have to make to get the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\lceil{\frac{N}{2}}\rceil$.

Basically, if you pick G cups, the probability that the correct cup was one of those G is $\frac{G}{N}$. So to have a 50% chance of picking the correct cup, you need to choose half of the total number of cups.

Comment: So for 100 (or 99) cups, I'll probably have to make 50 guesses? It seems odd, since for N=100, then after 30 guesses I have a 1/70 chance of getting it right, and after 50 guesses I have a 1/50 chance, etc. In other words after each guess it's like a new game all over again but for (N-1) cups

Comment: @PeterCheng It does seem odd, but it's true. If you make 51 guesses, even though the guesses individually were unlikely to be right (1/100, 1/99, 1/98, ... 1/51), the chances that *at least one* was right is much higher, $1/2$.

Comment: Is this because of a summation/factorial/product that reduces to N/2 (perhaps 1/N + 1/(N-1) + 1/(N-2) ...), or is it just trivial because 50% of N is N/2 ?

Comment: @PeterCheng There are different ways to see this. The simplest to me seems to be that if you randomly choose n out of the N cups, you have an n/N chance of having chosen some particular cup. To prove this more rigorously, use a counting argument. There are nCN (that's n choose N) ways to pick n cups out of N. How many of these include the cup with the ball? That's (n-1)C(N-1) (because you picked the ball, now you need n - 1 more cups). (n-1)C(N-1) / nCN = n/N and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

It may be clearer if you find the probability of **not** guessing correctly in G trials $\le$ 1/2.

$\frac{N-1}{N}\cdot\frac{N-2}{N-1}..... \frac{N-G}{N-G+1} = \frac{N-G}{N}$

First set $\frac{N-G}{N} = \frac12$, which yields G = $\frac{N}{2}$

Since $\frac{N}{2}$ may be a fraction, the answer is G = $\lceil\frac{N}{2}\rceil$

Comment: Very satisfying answer; just curious what the same formula would be (that arrives at 1/2) if you considered guessing **correctly** in G trials; maybe [1/N * 1/(N-1) * 1/(N-2) * ...] ?

Comment: That is not right, you can guess correctly only once !

Comment: So stop the product at [ ... * (N/2) ] , right?

Comment: Let us say there are 9 cups. Multiplication is used for AND type of probability, e.g. fail on 1st and fail on 2nd,...... i.e. 8/9 *7/8 *6/7 *5/6 *4/5 = 4/9 < 1/2, G = 5.
If you are talking of successes. it is an OR type of probability, each cup is equally likely to be correct with Pr = 1/9, and you ADD
so if you open 5 cups, Pr = 5/9.
I hope it is clear now. It is past midnight here, bye.